# Using ifelse for changing columns in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I would like to apply the ifelse condition to the following data frame according to the schema. I can do it repeatedly, but I have a lot of data.

**My code:**

```
d <- data.frame(x_1 = sample(1:100,10),x_2 = sample(1:100,10), y_1 =sample(1:100,10), y_2 =sample(1:100,10), 
                 y_3 =sample(1:100,10), y_4 =sample(1:100,10))
ifelse(d$x_1>d$y_1, 0, d$x_1-d$y_1)
ifelse(d$x_2>d$y_2, 0, d$x_2-d$y_2)
ifelse(d$x_1>d$y_3, 0, d$x_1-d$y_3)
ifelse(d$x_2>d$y_4, 0, d$x_2-d$y_4) # x_1>y_5..., x_2>y_6,...
```

**Edit:**

```
My x_.* are days of the week so I have x_1...x_7. But my y_.* are many. Code should work as follows:

x_1-y_1
x_2-y_2
x_3-y_3
x_4-y_4
x_5-y_5
x_6-y_6
x_7-y_7
x_1-y_8
x_2-y_9
.
.
.
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the result? Currently you are just printing it to console.

Comment: Do you want to compare every `x_.*` column with every `y_.*` column ?

Comment: You should check : https://www.guru99.com/r-apply-sapply-tapply.html

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I added explanation in Edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare every `x_.*` column with every `y_.*` column you can use `outer`.

First find out `"x"` and `"y"` columns.

```
x_col <- grep('x', names(d), value = TRUE)
y_col <- grep('y', names(d), value = TRUE)
```

We can create an index to subset `x_col`. The `ifelse` logic can be simplified to `pmin`

```
inds <- seq_along(y_col) %% length(x_col)
inds[inds == 0] <- length(x_col)
```

We can use `mapply` to subtract columns.

```
mapply(function(x, y) pmin(0, x - y), d[inds], d[y_col])
```

Comment: I don't want compare every x_.* column with every y_.*, but according to the schema I added in Edit.